# Android mapView: rotate overlay item

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, rotation, drawable

I want to rotate an overlay item (a drawable) according to my bearing onLocationChanged. How do I do this? I tried with the drawable, with the itemizedOverlay, and with the overlayItem, but no success.

```
public void bearingRotation(float boatBearing){                     
    Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)drawableCurrPos).getBitmap();          
    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(boatBearing);
    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), mat, true);

    drawableCurrPos = new BitmapDrawable(bMapRotate);                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you convert that drawable to bitmap.

```
 Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

Convert this bMapRotate using BitmapDrawable and apply that as a pin pointer to your location.

Comment: could you please be a little more precise about the pin pointer?

Comment: does this mean that I have to enable the itemized overlays for bitmaps as well as for drawables?

Comment: @Hannes.. If you are able to show your Overlay Item on map then above code is useful to rotate that drawable. when you want to rotate that drawable just remove the drawable from Overlay Item.Then rotate your drawable (in above case it is rotated by 90 degrees). Then again add that drawable to overlay item.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I've got it almost working. There is only one bug left, when I try to rotate the drawable onLocationChanged: The drawable rotates like crazy and then the app crashes. This is what I call onLocationChanged before

Comment: before I set the MapOverlay:
 public void bearingRotation(float boatBearing){      //rotate boat according to bearing
  Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)drawableCurrPos).getBitmap();   
  Matrix mat = new Matrix();
  mat.postRotate(boatBearing);
     //mat.postRotate(gpsMath.getGpsBearing());
     Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), mat, true);
          
     drawableCurrPos = new BitmapDrawable(bMapRotate);      
 }

Comment: @Hannes.. Great if I could help you :) (Since you are new to StackOverflow I will suggest If you feel this answer is correct you can accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark) :)

Comment: Is the way right how I add that drawable to overlay item again: I did it like this: drawableCurrPos = new BitmapDrawable(bMapRotate);

Comment: the correct way would be to do is... `mapOverlays.remove(customizedOverlay); //your customized overlay customizedOverlay = new CustomizedOverlay(drawableCurrPos,this,mapView); // This cunstructor may be` different in your case but the thing is jst pass the new drawable and add this new customizedOverlay to mapOverlays with `mapOverlays.add(customizedOverlay);`